# Resized UILabel snaps back to initial size

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

On detailview (Scrollview) in my app I have a UILabel that gets text that will have about 1000 words.

I want to resize it so the label fits - works fine so far

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
NSString *message = storycontent.text;
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(280,5000);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [message sizeWithFont:storycontent.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
CGRect newFrame = storycontent.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
storycontent.frame = newFrame;
}
```

When navigation to that detailview the label is resized as expected.
Now the weird thing: The moment I want to scroll down the UILabel snaps back to the initial size, so that only the first words are visible.

What can I do to avoid that behavior?

UPDATE:
When i delete the label and put in a new one it works fine. The strange behavior starts the moment i change the font size to something other then 17.

Comment: Rather than taking a Label take a textView

Comment: i get the same behavior by a textview. its resizing to the initial height of the object, when i start scrolling :(

Comment: can you please log your newFrame and storyContent frame

Comment: so some where else you are changing the Height ,once check in scrollView delegate methods is there any code related to label or textview height.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: you mean "autoresize subviews"?

Comment: Nope, I mean iOS 6 feature.

Comment: Go to the File inspector in interface builder, and untick "Use Auto Layout".

Comment: i had to google "Autolayout in iOS6" xD it seems to be fine now, besides scrolling does not work, but i will figure it out. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution (or workaround) was now to deactivate "Use Autolayout" (thx to Mark Kryzhanouski), which solves the snapping issue.

With not having the Autolayout the ScrollView does not automatically resize, so i added

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
```

and calculated a new FrameSize for it with the content size i already know from above, plus the static content that will be shown always.

```
NSString *message = storycontent.text;
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(280,5000);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [message sizeWithFont:storycontent.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(280,expectedLabelSize.height + 400)];
```

Maybe there is a way to do the same with "Use Autolayout" activated?!